# Error connection database mysql to spring boot (STS)

Tags: database-connection, dbconnection

Here I encountered an error on my database connection.
I've read some references but still can't find the answer to the cause of this error.

Error detail =https://pastebin.com/rqTSh7sG

[`Connection Database`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFjDq.jpg)

[`Program`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B62JX.jpg)